# pm2 zero downtime with remote deploy

Tags: nuxt.js, pm2

I've been trying to set up a small pipeline with PM2 using its deploy-functionality (from my ubuntu desktop to my remote ubuntu server). It pulls from my github & builds remotely and restarts it. PM2 has some nice features (as described here https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/guide/easy-deploy-with-ssh/) but I don't understand how I would prevent the downtime during the build-process of my somewhat massive Nuxt application. It's around 5-10 minutes.

I followed the steps in this article with the caveat that I also needed to SCP over my own .env-file.
https://warrenlee.tech/blog/deploy-your-nuxt-app-using-pm2

This is my ecosystem.config.js that I've added locally in my project folder:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'my-frontend',
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      instances: 'max', // Or a number of instances
      script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',
      args: 'start',
    }
  ],
  deploy : {
    // "production" is the environment name
    production : {
      "key": "/home/tobias/.ssh/apis.pem",
      "user": 'ubuntu',
      "host": ['myipaddresshere'],
      "ref": 'origin/master',
      "repo": 'git@github.com:myusername/my-frontend.git',
      "ssh_options": ['ForwardAgent=yes'],
      "path": '/home/ubuntu/frontend',
      "pre-deploy-local": `scp -i /home/tobias/.ssh/apis.pem /home/tobias/projects/my-frontend/.env ubuntu@random-ip-address9.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/frontend/current`,
      "post-deploy" : 'npm install && npm run build && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.config.js'
    }
  }
}
```

I'm thinking that I either:

1. Somehow try to build the project locally instead and scp it over
2. Find a more elegant way of using the way it's done right now but possibly copy/move around folders on the remote server, not really sure. The problem is that once the build starts it replaces the files that are being used for the live server. PM2 does have it's reload function so maybe that's better than to use startOrRestart.

Any advice on how to prevent the downtime from the build would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this, Thorvald?

Comment: It was some time ago but I looked at my source and tried to post an answer to the best of what I could remember. Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't expect a response. Thanks very much for this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since some people still struggle with this I figured I might as well post my solution (this was done for nuxt2). It ended up not as elegant as I'd hope, but it works. Basically, I use the pre deploy & post deploy hooks. In the first pre deploy hook I build the project locally on my dev computer, zip it and transfer the file using SCP to my remote server. In the post-deploy hook (which happens on the remote server) I unzip the folder, do some navigation, remove the old one and eventually restart the project. There's a lot of strange stuff being done with navigation and so forth, but that should be enough of a pointer to approximately how to do it. To understand more what the settings-file do I suggest you read the PM2 docs for the deployment.

This could probably be done with far more elegance, but at the time this is what I did.

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: 'project-name',
    // exec_mode: 'cluster', #TODO TURN ON IN ACTUAL PRODUCTION
    instances: '1', // Or a number of instances
    script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',
    args: 'start',
  }],
  deploy: {
    production: {
      "key": `/home/myubuntuusername/.ssh/awsapi`,
      "user": 'ubuntu',
      "host": ['ip-address-of-host'],
      "ref": 'origin/master',
      "repo": 'git@github.com:myorganisation/projectname.git',
      "ssh_options": ['ForwardAgent=yes'],
      "path": '/home/ubuntu/frontend',
      "pre-deploy-local": `echo ??????????????????!!!!!!!!!!!!REMEMBER TO SET DEBUG TO FALSE!!!!!!!!!!!!??????????????????? && npm install & npm run build && cd /home/yourusername/projects && zip -qr frontend.zip project_folder_name && scp -i /home/yourlocalusername/.ssh/yoursshkey /home/yourlocalusername/projects/frontend.zip ubuntu@randomipaddress.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/frontend`,
      "post-deploy": 'unzip -o /home/ubuntu/frontend/frontend.zip -d /home/ubuntu/frontend && cd /home/ubuntu/frontend && rm -rf current && mv -f /home/ubuntu/frontend/project_folder /home/ubuntu/frontend/current && cd /home/ubuntu/frontend/current && pm2 restart /home/ubuntu/frontend/current/ecosystem.config.js'
    }
  }
}
```